# Ionic - Onesignal - En handleNotificationReceived no me actualiza la vista

Tags: ionic, ionic-framework, onesignal

He intentado actualizar una array después de recibir una notificación de Onesignal:

**getMsg.ts** (simplificado):

```
...
getMsg = Array<Object> = [];
...
constructor( ... private oneSignal: OneSignal ... ) {
...

    this.oneSignal.handleNotificationReceived().subscribe( () => {

        this.getMessage();
        console.log('handleNotificationReceived');                
    } );
}

getMessage () {

    this.getMsg.push( { text: 'some text' } );

    console.log( 'getMessage' );

    // Funciona
    console.log( JSON.stringify( this.getMsg ) ); // [{"text":"some text"}]
}
```

**getMsg.html**:

```
...
<ion-list *ngFor="let m of getMsg">
    <ion-item>
        <p>{{ m.text }}</p>            
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
...
```

Pero no me funciona.

Tengo un `<textarea>` en mi archivo de `getMsg.html`, cuando introduzco algo adentro, la vista se actualiza mágicamente y me muestra los nuevos valores (después de que reciba una notificación).

Si utilizo la función `getMessage()` directamente, si me funciona.

Lo que he intentado también, es actualizar/recargar la vista con:

```
this.navCtrl.setRoot( this.navCtrl.getActive().component );
```

pero tampoco funciona.

```
Ionic: v3.4.0
Cordova: v7.0.1
```

Comment: Disculpa, ando buscando algo igual pero para Ionic v1, sabes como te colocare mi pregunta

Comment: aqui te dejo amigo, [enlace pregunta parecida con ionic v1](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/82060/actualizar-vista-al-llegar-la-informaci%C3%B3n-estando-dentro-de-esta)

Comment: @PedroMiguelPimientaMorales Hola Pedro... de momento estoy superliado... en cuando tenga un hueco te lo miro y a ver si te puedo echar un mano

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tras unos días de romperme el cerebro, lo pude solucionar con la ayuda de la siguiente página:

- [Understanding Zones and Change Detection in Ionic 2 & Angular 2](https://www.joshmorony.com/understanding-zones-and-change-detection-in-ionic-2-angular-2/)

> Angular 2 runs inside of its own special zone called NgZone. Running inside a zone allows one to detect when asynchronous tasks – things that can alter the internal state of an application, and therefore its views – start and finish. Since these asynchronous tasks are the only thing that are going to cause our views to change, by detecting when they are executed Angular 2 knows that a view may need to be updated.

Traducido seria ([google translate](https://translate.google.com/?hl=es#en/es/)) :

> Angular 2 corre dentro de su propia zona especial llamada NgZone. La
>   ejecución dentro de una zona permite detectar cuando se producen
>   tareas asíncronas, cosas que pueden alterar el estado interno de una
>   aplicación y, por lo tanto, sus vistas "*iniciar*" y "*finalizar*". Dado que
>   estas tareas asíncronas son la única cosa que va a hacer que nuestras
>   vistas cambien, y mediante la detección cuando se ejecutan, Angular 2 sabe que puede ser necesario actualizar una vista.

Código solución:

```
// Importamos NgZone
import { Component, NgZone } from '@angular/core';

// Lo agregamos al constructor 
constructor( ... private zone: NgZone, private oneSignal: OneSignal ... ) {
...

    this.oneSignal.handleNotificationReceived().subscribe( () => {

        this.getMessage();
    } );
}

getMessage () {

    // Y aquí ejecutamos "NgZone"   
    this.zone.run( () => {

        this.getMsg.push( { text: 'some text' } );

    } );       
}
```