# Actualizar vista al llegar la información estando dentro de esta

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic

Estoy recibiendo información a través de un `socket`, la cual inserto en el almacenamiento local del dispositivo, usando, `SQLite`. Pero me ocurre una duda, y es como poder actualizar dicha vista al estar dentro de ella misma.

No habría problema si me encuentro fuera de la vista o interfaz, en este caso el menú, ya que entonces al ingresar cargará la información de la tabla para la respectiva vista, y mostrará la información tomando todo lo de la tabla.

El problema aparece, si estoy ya en la vista, la información, llega al socket, el cual estaría en el fichero `javascript` que corresponde a la interfaz principal del menú, con lo cual no encuentro la forma de actualizar la vista estando dentro de ella misma.

#### Situacion N° 1[image: imagen 1]

En la imagen expuesta, la cual expongo la primera situación, en donde, si estoy en la interfaz de menú no hay problema, ya que ingreso a la interfaz correspondiente donde debe estar la nueva información.

#### Situacion N° 2 [image: imagen 2]

En esta situación, es en donde veo el problema. Si estoy dentro de dicha interfaz, la información llegara de manera normal a la aplicacion, desde el servidor, pero, no se recargara, al menos no mientras no salga e ingrese a la aplicacion.

#### Codigo

**horario.js **

```
angular.module('horarioEstudiante', ['ionic', 'ngCordova', 'btford.socket-io'])
       .controller('mostrarHorarioEstu', mostrarHorarioEstu)
       .factory('obtenerHorarioEstu', obtenerHorarioEstu)
       .factory('socket', socket);

mostrarHorarioEstu.$inject = ['$scope', 'obtenerHorarioEstu', 'socket'];

function mostrarHorarioEstu($scope, obtenerHorarioEstu, socket) {

    var Horario;

    obtenerHorarioEstu.datosHorario().then(function(informacion) {

        Horario = informacion;
        //console.log(Horario);

        $scope.horario = Horario;

    });

}  


obtenerHorarioEstu.$inject = ['$cordovaSQLite'];

function obtenerHorarioEstu($cordovaSQLite) {

    return {

        insertarHorario: function(Horario){ acciones },
        datosHorario: function() { acciones }
    };
}
```

**menu.js**

```
angular.module('historialApp', ['ionic', 'ngCordova', 'horarioEstudiante', 'calificacionesEstudiante'])
    .controller('borrarHistorial', borrarHistorial)
    .factory('salirApp', salirApp);


borrarHistorial.$inject = ['$scope', '$ionicHistory', 'salirApp', '$ionicPopup',
                           '$state', '$timeout', '$window', 'socket', 'sk'];

function borrarHistorial($scope, $ionicHistory, salirApp, $ionicPopup, $state, $timeout, $window, socket, sk) {    

    socket.on('envio', function(data) {

        var dato = data;
        console.log(dato); 

        obtenerHorarioEstu.insertarHorario(dato);
        
    });
}
```

Comment: Buenas, te hago una consulta, la aplicación recibe la información, pero el problema es que no se refresca una de las vistas? Probaste con broadcast y listen?

Comment: Hola, has intentado colocar en la vista en el `ion-view` colocando `cache-view="false"`?

Comment: @KN_ la cuestion radica, en que como actualizo dicha informacion, si estoy dentro de la misma pagina, si puedes ir al chat es mejor

Comment: Hola Pedro... el otro día tuve el mismo problema.. mira si te ayuda algo esto: [link](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/80014/ionic-onesignal-en-handlenotificationreceived-no-me-actualiza-la-vista/81815#81815)

Comment: echando ojo, te respondo luego

Comment: no necesitas sobre escribir la informacion recibida o en este caso refrescar la vista???

Comment: @FranciscoNúñez pues de sobre escribir en este momento, no es algo que me preocupa, si mas bien refrescar la vista aun estando dentro de esta.

Comment: @KN_ puedes colocar tu respuesta, eso es exactamente lo que buscaba

Comment: Publicada, me alegra mucho que haya servido. Saludos!!

Answer (score 1):

De acuerdo a tus comentarios, voy a postear la última versión a la que llegamos:

**Controlador Principal**: Aquí se recibe la llamada desde el servicio en el $on:

```
app.controller('mostrarHorarioEstu', function($scope, obtenerHorarioEstu) {
  $scope.name = 'World';

  $scope.$on('cambia-valor',function(){
    $scope.name = obtenerHorarioEstu.acciones ;
  })
});
```

**Controlador Secundario**: Desde aquí se llama al servicio:

```
app.controller('borrarHistorial', function($scope, obtenerHorarioEstu){
  $scope.val = '';
  $scope.enviar = function(){
    obtenerHorarioEstu.envia($scope.val);
  }

});
```

**Servicio**: Aquí se recibe la información y se almacena para luego ser enviada a todos los subscriptores a través de un $broadcast:

```
app.factory('obtenerHorarioEstu',function($rootScope){
  var service = this;
  service.acciones  = 'no-cambia';

  service.envia = function(data){
    service.acciones  = data;
    $rootScope.$broadcast('cambia-valor');
  }



  return service;
})
```

Ejemplo funcional: http://plnkr.co/edit/s4EQiLYFvMMRKpWLnb4V?p=preview

Esta solución se vasa en la utilización de servicios de angular y $broadcast (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope)

Saludos